# ASP.NET Core MVC - Como puedo guardar la fecha ingresada en un datepicker?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-tabla

Agradezco mucho que me pudieran ayudar, como puedo guardar la fecha ingresada en un datepicker para poder pasarla en cambio del DateTime.Now y poder calcular la diferencia de días de acuerdo a lo que ingresa el usuario?

```
<tbody id="myTable">
            @*=========== CUERPO DE LA TABLA ============*@
            @foreach (var resumen2 in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@resumen2.CHB_BL </td>
                    <td>@resumen2.CHE_Equipment_Number</td>
                    <td>@resumen2.CCD_Number_of_Free_Days </td>
                    <td>@resumen2.CCD_Last_Free_Day_Date </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" id="datetime" class="btn-outline-grey">
                    </td>
                    <td>@resumen2.CCD_Chargeable_Days</td>
                    <td>
                        @{
                            DateTime fechaInicial = DateTime.Now;
                            DateTime fechaFinal = resumen2.CCD_Last_Free_Day_Date;
                            TimeSpan tSpan = fechaInicial - fechaFinal;
                            int Dias = tSpan.Days;
                            @(Dias)
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>@resumen2.CCD_Chargeable_Amount</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrias hacer con js guardando la fecha en una variable o con una base de datos

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
```

> En C# la diferencia se sacaria asi para darte un ejemplo

```
    DateTime elem = new DateTime(2022, 02, 12);
    DateTime elem2 = new DateTime(2022, 04, 10);
    

    Console.WriteLine("Diferencia de dias: " + (elem - elem2).Days);
```

Comment: muchas gracias Raul por tu ayuda pero no me funciono!